# (Beginner networking) Can I use a crossover cable to connect a PC to a hub that has an uplink feature?

Tags: cable

I am taking a class on Computer Networking and part of a lab we did earlier this week involved connecting our PC to a hub using a straight-through cable. It worked. Then we had a small experiment with connecting our hub to another group's hub using a straight-through cable instead of a crossover cable. We were not connected at the point, but then we enabled the "uplink" button which apparently lets us emulate a crossover cable by physically reversing the circuitry, and we became connected.

Now I am wondering if it would be possible to do something different. Would it be possible to connect a PC to the hub we were using with only a crossover cable if we used the uplink feature as well? (We used straight-through previously).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is yes you can. Lets start with the basics that you described:

```
Host   >  X Cable   >  Host
Host   >  Straight  >  Switch
Switch >  X Cable   >  Switch
```

This is because there are two types of devices in networking, DTE (Data Terminal Equipment) or DCE (Data Communications Equipment). And devices of the same type need a Cross over cable to connect them, those of different types can be connected with a straight cable. Here are some examples of types:

```
DCE              DTE
Switch           PC
Hub              Printer
                 Router
```

One of the first improvements made to switches was to add a manual uplink button as you describe, this puts add a cross to any cable; a straight cable becomes a cross, and a cross becomes a double cross (really angry?) which is the same a straight. So then you can have:

```
Switch  >  Straight  > Uplink  >  Switch
Host    >  X cable   > Uplink  >  Switch
```

New switches can have a feature called Auto MDI-X. Which detects the combination of cable type you have used and what the end device is and automatically sets the port for you, so like magic it just works!

Comment: Network interfaces in (non-switch) devices have also supported Auto MDI-X for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

The uplink feature you refer to is Auto MDI-X.
Its common for a hub to have several MDI interfaces and one Auto MDI-X interface.
If all ports were Auto MDI-X it wouldn't matter which type of cable you used, straight through or crossover.

Comment: If there is an 'uplink' button then I am not sure this will be Auto MDI-X, it sounds more manual to me :)

Comment: Auto is just that: *automatic* (There's no button) The "uplink" button is a switch that physically swaps the TX/RX pairs.